# are there any tricks to working with overloaded methods in specs2?

Tags: scala, mockito, specs2

i've been getting beat up attempting to match on an overloaded method.

i'm new to scala and specs2, so that is likely one factor ;)

so i have a mock of this [SchedulerDriver class](http://mesos.apache.org/api/latest/java/org/apache/mesos/SchedulerDriver.html)

and i'm trying to verify the content of the arguments that are being
passed to the signature of this launchTasks method:

http://mesos.apache.org/api/latest/java/org/apache/mesos/SchedulerDriver.html#launchTasks(java.util.Collection,%20java.util.Collection)

i have tried the `answers` style like so:

```
val mockSchedulerDriver = mock[SchedulerDriver]
mockSchedulerDriver.launchTasks(haveInterface[Collection[OfferID]], haveInterface[Collection[TaskInfo]]) answers { i => System.out.println(s"i=$i") }
```

and get

`ambiguous reference to overloaded definition, both method launchTasks in trait SchedulerDriver of type (x$1: org.apache.mesos.Protos.OfferID, x$2: java.util.Collection[org.apache.mesos.Protos.TaskInfo])org.apache.mesos.Protos.Status and method launchTasks in trait SchedulerDriver of type (x$1: java.util.Collection[org.apache.mesos.Protos.OfferID], x$2: java.util.Collection[org.apache.mesos.Protos.TaskInfo])org.apache.mesos.Protos.Status match argument types (org.specs2.matcher.Matcher[Any],org.specs2.matcher.Matcher[Any])`

and i have tried the `capture` style like so:

```
val mockSchedulerDriver = mock[SchedulerDriver]
val offerIdCollectionCaptor = capture[Collection[OfferID]]
val taskInfoCollectionCaptor = capture[Collection[TaskInfo]]
there was one(mockSchedulerDriver).launchTasks(offerIdCollectionCaptor, taskInfoCollectionCaptor)
```

and get:

`overloaded method value launchTasks with alternatives: (x$1: org.apache.mesos.Protos.OfferID,x$2: java.util.Collection[org.apache.mesos.Protos.TaskInfo])org.apache.mesos.Protos.Status <and> (x$1: java.util.Collection[org.apache.mesos.Protos.OfferID],x$2: java.util.Collection[org.apache.mesos.Protos.TaskInfo])org.apache.mesos.Protos.Status cannot be applied to (org.specs2.mock.mockito.ArgumentCapture[java.util.Collection[mesosphere.mesos.protos.OfferID]], org.specs2.mock.mockito.ArgumentCapture[java.util.Collection[org.apache.mesos.Protos.TaskInfo]])`

any guidance or suggestions on how to approach this appreciated...!

best,
tony.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `any` matcher in that case:

```
val mockSchedulerDriver = mock[SchedulerDriver]

mockSchedulerDriver.launchTasks(
 any[Collection[OfferID]],     
 any[Collection[TaskInfo]]) answers { i => System.out.println(s"i=$i")
```

The difference is that `any[T]` is a `Matcher[T]` and the overloading resolution works in that case (whereas `haveInterface` is a `Matcher[AnyRef]` so it can't direct the overloading resolution).

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why the first alternative didn't work, but the second alternative isn't working because scala doesn't consider implicit functions when resolving which overloaded method to call, and the magic that lets you use a `capture` as though it were the thing you captured depends on an implicit function call.

So what if you make it explicit?

```
val mockSchedulerDriver = mock[SchedulerDriver]
val offerIdCollectionCaptor = capture[Collection[OfferID]]
val taskInfoCollectionCaptor = capture[Collection[TaskInfo]]
there was one(mockSchedulerDriver).launchTasks(
    offerIdCollectionCaptor.capture, taskInfoCollectionCaptor.capture)
```

Comment: hi @daniel, thanks for your response. unfortunately, i see the same issue when explicitly calling with `.capture`...